# Symfony Embedded Form Conditional Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form which contains three objects:

```
$builder
    ->add('customer', new CustomerType())
    ->add('shippingAddress', new AddressType())
    ->add('billingAddress', new AddressType())
    ->add('sameAsShipping', 'checkbox', ['mapped' => false])
;
```

Each of the embedded forms has their own validation constraints and they work.  In my main form, I have `cascade_validation => true` so that all of the embedded form validation constraints are applied.  This also works.

I am having trouble 'disabling' the validation on the `billingAddress` form if the `sameAsShipping` checkbox is enabled.  I can't make the validation in the AddressType form conditional because it always needs to be enforced for the shippingAddress form.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this same problem by using validation groups.

First, **this is important:** use the `validation_groups` option in your `AddressType` to set the validation groups **of every constraint of each field** in the type:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class AddressType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $groups = $options['validation_groups'];

        $builder->add('firstName', 'text', ['constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(['groups' => $groups])]);
        $builder->add('lastName', 'text', ['constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(['groups' => $groups])]);
    }
}
```

Then, in the parent form pass different validation groups to the two fields:

```
<?php

$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('checkout', 'form', null, [
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ])
    ->add('billingAddress', 'address', [
        'validation_groups' => 'billingAddress'
    ])
    ->add('shippingAddress', 'address', [
        'validation_groups' => 'shippingAddress'
    ]);
```

Then, determine determine your validation groups by looking at the value of the checkbox.

```
if ($request->request->get('sameAsShipping')) {
    $checkoutValidationGroups = ['Default', 'billingAddress'];
} else {
    $checkoutValidationGroups = ['Default', 'billingAddress', 'shippingAddress'];
}
```

You can then validate only either the `billingAddress` or the `shippingAddress`, or both using the validation group mechanism.

I chose to use a button:

```
$formBuilder->add('submitButton', 'submit', ['validation_groups' => $checkoutValidationGroups]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a form model (I use it in nearly every form, but this code here is not tested):

```
/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequenceProvider()
 */
class YourForm implements GroupSequenceProviderInterface {
  /**
   * @Assert\Valid()
   */
  private $customer;

  /**
   * @Assert\Valid()
   */
  private $shippingAddress;

  /**
   * @Assert\Valid(groups={'BillingAddressRequired'})
   */
  private $billingAddress;

  private $billingSameAsShipping;

  public function getGroupSequence() {
    $groups = ['YourForm'];

    if(!$this->billingSameAsShipping) {
      $groups[] = 'BillingAddressRequired';
    }

    return $groups;
  }
}
```

Try to use meaningful names. `sameAsShipping` is hard to understand. Read the if-condition in `getGroupSequence`: if not billing (address) same as shipping (address) then billing address required.

That's all, clear code in my opinion.